# What alarm/access hardware can I control from *NIX?

Tags: python, api, hardware

Okay, so not strictly a programming question BUT the point is I want to integrate my new building's business access/alarm system into the rest of my *NIX setup at my business.  I do NOT want to use some cruddy windows GUI program written for Windows XP SP1 that manages a bare circuit-board via a serial connection and provides absolutely zero APIs.  There's got to be something decent out there!

Any decent access/alarm hardware vendors out there?  I'd love to interface via python, perl, ruby, etc. to some nice control panel that has an integrated NIC. Heck, I'd even settle for some CLI tool that I could at least exec and parse.

We've got  mag card readers on doors/elevators, mag locks,  rex's, fingerprint readers, etc. for our access.

We've got standard door/window, motion, etc. for our alarm.

Hardware vendor suggestions?

Comment: "some cruddy windows GUI program written for Windows XP SP1 that manages a bare circuit-board via a serial connection and provides absolutely zero APIs" sounds perfect .... if documentation for the serial protocol is available.  Just throw away the Windows software install discs.

Comment: No, not really.  I have no desire to run 100+ serial cables up to 800 feet to some kind of monstrosity that can handle 100+ serial connections and then license/buy a vendors serial interface documentation and program serial-port interaction myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding some good hardware by eData that was run off of embedded Linux with ssh, SOAP, REST, and Web GUI access.  Unfortunately the integrator bid way too high and wouldn't commit to working in our time frame, so we ended up with the crappy Kantech stuff.  Yay serial cables.  :-(

Comment: Just in case someone else finds this... In 2017, with Kantech, you can do Ethernet and IP networks for the door controllers, same quality of software and painful windows environment though.

Answer (score 1):

What is you physical location? If europe you could have a look at EIB-Technologies. Just google for EIB and you'll see many answers for your question. EIB stands for European Installation Bus. It is a technology used for controlling almost everything in buildings (light, alarms, aircon, etc...) using a bus and centralized control centers. Depending on technology providers you'll also have interfaces to *nix systems.

have a look at e.g. [link text](http://www.bb-steuerungstechnik.de/cms/gebaeudeautomation.html?gclid=CLj20YbGyKYCFYMI3wodAlVVGg)

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Apparently EIB also stands for "European Investment Bank".  Anyway, I googled around a bit, and it seems that the hardware is only sold through distributors, and it doesn't appear to be readily available in the US.  Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.  I wouldn't mind evaluating it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you actually want to do with your integrated system?

Two of my former employers developed access control systems, both running on Windows. Both provided a programmatic API (DCOM or TCP socket.) *NIX support was another matter, but you avoid the hardware interfacing problem, at least.

One was Honeywell, but that's designed for *big* systems and will probably be out of your price (and complexity) range. The other (a small startup) doesn't support all of the devices you list.

If your building wiring is RS485, you're unlikely to be allowed to interface over that. Ethernet to the access control software is your best bet.

Ethernet-connected devices have traditionally been uncommon as the configuration is tricky; your typical alarm installer doesn't know about IP addresses, subnets, switches and whatnot.

Comment: We're building our own 5-story building, as the owners, and occupying nearly all of it ourselves.  We _want_ to be able to do whatever we feel like doing with the alarm system, quite like we are able to do pretty much whatever we want to do with our asterisk phone systems (anything we can program, it can do).  For instance, we'd like to tie it into our site-wide server-monitoring and alert system we built ourselves.  Or alert our own people via text message, automated call, email, or whatever differently depending on the hour or day, etc.  Not just "what monitoring company shall it call?"

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the way to go will be DPWS; as Windows provides built-in support for this now, you can expect hardware vendors to jump on the bandwagon.

Comment: DPWS appears to be a protocol, which is a start, but it's not hardware.  I suppose you mean to search around for hardware that supports DPWS.  Unfortunately, googling around for DPWS hardware brings up THIS THREAD and no useful hardware links.  :-/